# How to extract data elements from selected rows in a DT table with R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

A previous question/answer on StackOverflow got me this far with a toy problem...

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(df)
               )
      ),
      actionButton(inputId = "ErrorButton", label="Comment on selected rows")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    df %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
  })
  
  currentModalIndex <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    currentModalIndex(1) # reset index to 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(currentModalIndex(), {
    if (currentModalIndex() > 0 && currentModalIndex() <= length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      myString <- paste("You have selected row", input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()])
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Report possible data error",
        myString,
        footer = actionButton("nextModal", "Next"),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        fade = TRUE
      ))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextModal, {
    if (currentModalIndex() < length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      currentModalIndex(currentModalIndex() + 1)
    } else {
      currentModalIndex(0) # reset index to 0, indicating no more modals to show
      removeModal()
    }
  })

  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                             lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                             paging = TRUE,
                             searching = TRUE,
                             fixedColumns = TRUE,
                             autoWidth = TRUE,
                             ordering = TRUE,
                             dom = 'tlip',
                             buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
              )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So if I were to run that app and select the 1st and 3rd rows in the data table and then hit the "Comment on Selected Rows" button I would get a modal that said "You have selected row 1" and then when I clicked "Next" I would get a modal that said "You have selected row 3".   So far so good...

What I need to do now is to access the individual columns of those selected rows.  Ultimately my real app will be building an SQL string to update a table with the elements of the selected rows.  For purposes of this toy problem, it would be sufficient if I could make the modal string say "You have selected the row for `firstName` `lastName`" if that makes sense.

I have been playing around with this for a couple of days and can't seem to crack it.  I have found other examples but none that quite fit.

EDIT:
YBS provided an answer below that I thought was what I needed, but it only works in the case where the entire dataset is present in the data table.  Bad on me for not realizing the toy problem didn't fully capture the problem.  Consider the modified app below

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
gender <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors, gender)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(df)
               )
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "gender",
                        label = "Gender", 
                        choices = c("Male", "Female")
            ),
      actionButton(inputId = "ErrorButton", label="Comment on selected rows")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    df %>% filter(gender == input$gender) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
  })

  currentModalIndex <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    currentModalIndex(1) # reset index to 1
  })

  observeEvent(currentModalIndex(), {
    if (currentModalIndex() > 0 && currentModalIndex() <= length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      myString <- paste("You have selected row", input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()])
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Report possible data error",
        myString,
        footer = actionButton("nextModal", "Next"),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        fade = TRUE
      ))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$nextModal, {
    if (currentModalIndex() < length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      currentModalIndex(currentModalIndex() + 1)
    } else {
      currentModalIndex(0) # reset index to 0, indicating no more modals to show
      removeModal()
    }
  })

  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                             lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                             paging = TRUE,
                             searching = TRUE,
                             fixedColumns = TRUE,
                             autoWidth = TRUE,
                             ordering = TRUE,
                             dom = 'tlip',
                             buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
              )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So now the table is only showing the rows that match the selected gender.  If I run that app and select Male for the gender, the table has three rows: Bob Smith, Jim Thomas, and Billy Idol.  If I select rows 1 and 3 (Bob Smith and Billy Idol) and hit the button, the first modal is correct ("You have selected the row for Bob Smith") but the second modal (should be for Billy Idol) says "You have selected the row for Jim Thomas"

I understand this is because the Jim Thomas record is the third row in the dataframe, not the datatable...but how can you make sure this indexing is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
observeEvent(currentModalIndex(), {
    if (currentModalIndex() > 0 && currentModalIndex() <= length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
      df <- filtered_df()
      fname <- df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"firstNames"]
      lname <- df[input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[currentModalIndex()],"lastNames"]
      myString <- paste("You have selected the row for ", fname, lname)
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Report possible data error",
        myString,
        footer = actionButton("nextModal", "Next"),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        fade = TRUE
      ))
    }
  })
```

Comment: This works when the DT table has the whole dataframe, but not if it's filtered in any way.  My bad for not having a minimal example that was too minimal....see the edit to the OP above.  And thanks!